# Difference between class-target and class-native in yocto recipe

Tags: parsing, compilation, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to understand Yocto recipes.

Following is one of the line from a Yocto Recipe:

```
DEPENDS_append_class-target = " grub-efi-native"
```

What I understood is this recipe depends on package `grub-efi-native`, while on the other hand, what I am trying to understand is `class-target` field.

There are two variables which are present in the manual, `class-target` and `class-native`.

This is the statement from the Yocto Manual.

```
Inside the recipe, use _class-native and _class-target overrides to specify any functionality specific to the respective native or target case.
```

Can anyone explain what the above statement means? Does it mean that it depends on the target binary and not host binary?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bitbake can use the same recipe to build a recipe for either the target, or the native build host. This is enabled by having `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"` in the recipe. This will enable you to use -native to refer to a build of the recipe for the native build host.

But sometimes there's a difference in how you want to build that recipe depending on if you're building for the target or the host, this is when `_class-target` or `_class-native` can be used.

So in your example the `DEPENDS_append_class-target = " grub-efi-native"` line means that when building this recipe for the target, DEPENDS will ***also*** include `grub-efi-native`.